# React Native multiple selectors

Tags: reactjs, react-native

how can I do to build this functionality in react native? When the user clicks on "Add a language" a component is added and he can select a language.
in the state variable as a result I want the Ids selected [language_id_1, language_id_2]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array with the selectors `array.push({selector:<selector></selector>, id : null})` every time you click the add language you push one more selector into the array. On the render just cicle through the array and write the selector `array[i].selector`. And do a on change of the language and set the id of the selector to the id of the language `onChange={(language)=>{array[i].id = language}}`

Answer (score 0):

please add some code for us to be more helpful in terms of actual solution, but in general, with react-native, you can use all of react state power. just do something like -

---

```
 const [ lang, setLang ] = useState([]) //for initial 

 setLang([...lang, [`lang_id_${lang.length + 1}`] : event.target.value]) //for adding lang, assuming it comes ass event.target.value
```

---

and then creating views in loop

---

```
 return (
     <>
      { lang.map( lan => <View> { lan } </View> )}
     </>
    )
```

---